# How to change color in Stepper according to active and completed Step

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, angular-material-stepper

***Reactjs,MaterialUI***

I am using reactjs and material ui in my project and i want to change color of StepConnector and Button inside Step if it is active or completed.i want to change color of StepConnector and Button if next step is Active.Below is the code i am using:

```
const Cart = () => {

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        minHeight: "800px",
        bgcolor: "#F6F9FC",
        width: "100%",
      }}
    >
      <Stepper
        nonLinear
        activeStep={activeStep}
        sx={{
          maxWidth: "60%",
          marginLeft: "10%",
          "& .MuiStepConnector-line": {
            borderColor: "#085E7D",
            borderTopWidth: "4px",
            minWidth: "30px",
          },
        }}
      >
        {steps.map((label, index) => (
          <Step key={label} sx={{ padding: "0px" }}>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              onClick={handleStep(index)}
              completed={completed[index]}
              sx={{
                bgcolor: "#085E7D",
                borderRadius: "25px",
                "&:hover": {
                  backgroundColor: "#085E7D",
                  boxShadow: "none",
                  textShadow: "none",
                  margin: "0px",
                },
              }}
            >
              {label}
            </Button>
          </Step>
        ))}
      </Stepper>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

Please help me in my code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code snippet doesn't really give enough context to fully answer your question (not sure how the buttons are working?). However if I use this [example](https://mui.com/components/steppers/#HorizontalLinearStepper.js) from the MUI website, the following change to the Stepper results in the connector lines changing color when the next step is "active" and "complete".

```
<Stepper
  activeStep={activeStep}
  sx={{
    "& .MuiStepConnector-line": {
      borderTopWidth: "4px",
    },
    "& .MuiStepConnector-root.Mui-active .MuiStepConnector-line": {
      borderColor: "red",
    },
    "& .MuiStepConnector-root.Mui-completed .MuiStepConnector-line": {
      borderColor: "green",
    },
 }}
>
```

Comment: stackoverflow didnt allowed me to add more code thats why i trimmed it

Comment: Does the above snippet work for styling your line?

Comment: but if i am on the third step connector between second step and third step only is changing in this condition i want show the line betnween first step and second also as colored

Comment: rather it is completed or not doesnt matter

Comment: Without seeing your exact example, I cannot provide any more details. It sounds like you might have state being applied in a way that doesn't work with the code snippet I supplied. You'll need to look at the class's that are applied to the line when it's not colored how you'd like and adjust the css selectors in your `sx` prop accordingly so that it applies under the right conditions.

Comment: you can see my code here please visit it and help me https://pastebin.com/DkcmzCw7